# How do I divide a set of data samples which follow a logarithmic distribution?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, logarithms

I'm working for the first time with Logarithmic distribution. I have a set of samples which follow logarithmic distribution. I extracted the maximum and the minimum values from the set and defined the interval as [min,max]. Now I need to partition this range into 5 parts. Say [min,a], [a,b], [b,c], [c,d] and [d,max].

If I calculate the mean, then I get two splices. I need 5 such. How do I go about it? Any pointers on articles, web pages and sources that describe and explain related concepts are also well appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two natural ways are equal intervals, so $a=\min+(\max-\min)/5$ and so on, and equal ratios, so define $r=\left(\frac {\max}{\min}\right)^{\frac 15}$, then $a=r\min, b=r^2 \min$,etc.  These work for any distribution.  Ratios doesn't work if $\min \lt 0 \lt \max$

Comment: Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0):

At the end, I just divided the interval into equal parts. It worked. The client hasn't come back saying anything. It was neatly accepted. The client was Mercedes AMG group.